# Scrollbar causes shift of flexbox based list elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, flexbox

I'm having a simple list like the following

[image]

Rows and header have `display:flex`. All cells are having `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` equal to `1`. As you can see (especialy its noticeable at col 5) columns are shifted because of scroll bar.

How can that be fixed?

`overflow-y:scroll` is not an option. This is an angular app and I've tried to do `[ngStyle]="{'width.px': rows.clientWidth - 50 }"` where `50` is left+right `margin` of rows. But that's also not good because first rows are rendered and only after that width of header is decreased, so user will see jump. So I guess css-only solution is much better than using angular.

Comment: need some code to debug. Alone image will not help